# ReactJs - Looping and returning state in a reducer

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have an array of id's

```
const arr = ["0", "1"];
```

and in switch case of my reducer the code looks like

```
arr.map((k) => {
      const itemIndex = state.getIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable']).findIndex((item) => item.get('id') === k);
      if (action.actionType === 'deleteMultipleRows') {
        console.log(itemIndex);
        return state
          .deleteIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable', itemIndex]);
      }
      if (action.actionType === 'toggleFlagForMultipleRows') {
        return state
          .setIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable', itemIndex, 'flagStatus'], action.payload.status);
      }
    });
```

and the state looks something like this

```
{
  route: {
    location: {
      pathname: '/data/3',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      key: 'imniz2'
    }
  },
  language: {
    locale: 'en'
  },
  appPage: {},
  dataFilePage: {
    loading: false,
    tableData: {
      dataFileName: {
        id: '1',
        start_date_time: '1502843882',
        end_date_time: '1502930282',
        name: 'Time Tag CSV 12.02.2017',
        component: 'zPV',
        tags: '#abc111 #abc113 #hpv'
      },
      headers: [
        'id',
        'DateTime',
        'ARF_CHWR_Temp',
        'ARF_CHWS_Temp',
        'ARF_SCHWP_Magflo',
        'flagStatus'
      ],
      data: [ ],
      dataForTable: [
        {
          id: '0',
          DateTime: '1534398905',
          ARF_CHWR_Temp: 19.07981,
          ARF_CHWS_Temp: 5.8339,
          ARF_SCHWP_Magflo: 5.150002,
          flagStatus: false
        },
        {
          id: '1',
          DateTime: '1534398965',
          ARF_CHWR_Temp: 19.43713,
          ARF_CHWS_Temp: 5.795691,
          ARF_SCHWP_Magflo: 5.699998,
          flagStatus: false
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          DateTime: '1534398905',
          ARF_CHWR_Temp: 19.17568,
          ARF_CHWS_Temp: 5.805243,
          ARF_SCHWP_Magflo: 5.774999,
          flagStatus: false
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that the changes are not happening in the store and I have no clue why. I think its something related to `return` statement in the `.map`. I have checked the code properly and there's nothing really wrong in any other place. The console even shows up after the event in dispatched.

Reducer for that specific container is :-

```
/*
 *
 * DataFilePage reducer
 *
 */

import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { LOAD_DATA_FILE, LOAD_DATA_FILE_SUCCESS, ACTION_DISPATCHED_IN_DATA_TABLE, ACTION_DISPATCHED_IN_DATA_TABLE_SUCCESS } from './constants';

export const initialState = fromJS({
  loading: false,
  tableData: {},
});

function dataFilePageReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_DATA_FILE:
      return state.set('loading', true);
    case LOAD_DATA_FILE_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .set('tableData', fromJS(action.payload))
        .set('loading', false);
    case ACTION_DISPATCHED_IN_DATA_TABLE:{
      if (action.payload.id !== undefined && action.payload.id !== null) { // for single row operations
        const itemIndex = state.getIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable']).findIndex((item) => item.get('id') === action.payload.id);
        // console.log('reducer item index', itemIndex);
        if (itemIndex !== undefined && itemIndex !== null) {
          if (action.actionType === 'toggleFlag') {
            return state
              .setIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable', itemIndex, 'flagStatus'], action.payload.status);
          }
          if (action.actionType === 'editTableData') {
            return state
              .updateIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable', itemIndex], item => fromJS(action.payload));
          }
          if (action.actionType === 'deleteRow') {
            return state
              .deleteIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable', itemIndex]);
          }
        }
      }
      if (action.payload.selectedRowKeys.length > 0) { // for multiple row operations
        action.payload.selectedRowKeys.map((k) => {
          const itemIndex = state.getIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable']).findIndex((item) => item.get('id') === k);
          if (action.actionType === 'deleteMultipleRows') {
            return state
              .deleteIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable', itemIndex]);
          }
          if (action.actionType === 'toggleFlagForMultipleRows') {
            return state
              .setIn(['tableData', 'dataForTable', itemIndex, 'flagStatus'], action.payload.status);
          }
        });
      }
      return state;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default dataFilePageReducer;
```

Comment: Your map will return, for every element in arr, a new value. In your map you are returning new versions of state - however you aren’t then actually returning anything from your reducer. Take another look at how you can end up with one single new version of state that you then return.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Looking into that now.

Comment: @chrisCousins I tried a few things but was not able to make it work :( Any idea or direction on how should I proceed with it?

Comment: Please post what you tried

Comment: @ChrisCousins sorry for replying this late, but I actually tried a bunch of things and moved ahead, probably gonna go back to it in a while then I will post it for sure. Thanks for help though.

Comment: Please post your whole reducer

Comment: @ChrisCousins I am using components and containers approach in my app, I have added the code of my reducer file.